# Error while mapping objects using Ultramapper

Tags: c#, ultramapper

Got below exception while trying to map `List<Exams>` to `List<ExamsDto>` :

> Expression of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be used for parameter of
>   type 'System.Object' of method 'Void
>   <.cctor>b__18_2(UltraMapper.ReferenceTracking, System.Object,
>   System.Type, System.Object)'

```
public class Exam: MongoDoc
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObjectId CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }

    public BsonDateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public BsonDateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class ExamDto
{
  public bool IsActive { get; set; }
  public string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
  public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
  public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
  public bool Inactive { get; set; }

}
```

```
var mapper = new UltraMapper.Mapper(cfg =>
{
    cfg.MapTypes<Nullable<DateTime>, string>(dest => dest.HasValue ? dest.ToString() : "");
    cfg.MapTypes<ObjectId, string>(typeMappingConfig =>    typeMappingConfig.ToString());
    cfg.MapTypes<string, ObjectId>(typeMappingConfig => ObjectId.Parse(typeMappingConfig));
});

var result = mapper.Map<List<ExamDto>>(exams);
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what you are doing and how the error came about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with mapping dateTime to BsonDateTime.

Need to add explicit conversion

```
cfg.MapTypes<BsonDateTime, DateTime>(dest => dest.ToUniversalTime());
```